# How to remove the number of a comment in the url slug?

Tags: comments, urls

Searched through google but can't find anything related to it. Either I don't know what terms to use when searching or there's nothing about it.

I want to remove #comment-* we all know that it appears after some1 is submitting a comment.

So any thoughts on that one?

SOLVED:
I used a hook to redirect from the page where the comment was first submitted

```
add_filter('comment_post_redirect', 'redirect_after_comment');
function redirect_after_comment($location)
{
  return $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
}
```

Maybe will help someone in near future.

Comment: Please **do not** put your solution into the question. Write a real answer instead, and mark the question as answered then.

Answer (score 2):

The asker solved the issue with `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` but refused to post that as a real solution.

Let me suggest something better, because the referer might be empty or full of malicious code. Never use that.

First, we make sure, we get *both* arguments for that hook:

```
add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', 'wpse_97580_comment_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

Then we use the post ID of the comment to generate a safe URL for redirection:

```
function wpse_97580_comment_redirect( $location, $comment )
{
    return get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID );
}
```

In my opinion, this is bad for usability: the user might have to search her comment now on a long page.